# How to proxy from React client to Springboot server

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku, proxy

I have a React client and a Springboot server.  I have them running separately.  In my package.json, I have proxy set to localhost:8080.  But when I deploy to Heroku, I get `Invalid Header`.

If I remove it,  then when the client has a url such as /api/auth, it is trying to find it on the front-end server instead of using the back-end server

Have read several possible solutions, such as creating an `.env` file with `HOST=my-server.herokuapp.com` as well as installing `http-proxy-middleware` and adding a file called `setupProxy.js` with the contents

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://my-server.herokuapp.com',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

None of this resolved the problem.

I've seen mention of webpack, but I'm new to Javascript frameworks, so I'm not familiar with that.  I just have React and I start it with `npm start`

Comment: Peter ,did you ever find a solution to your issue? I'm experiencing a similar problem using a setupProxy file to manage the middleware proxy connection from a React frontend to a Spring Boot server, running as separate apps on Heroku. It doesn't appear that the http-proxy-middleware function is being called upon API requests, even though its being explicitly exported in a separate src/setupProxy.js file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on this project anymore and I don't remember what I did for this specific issue.  But after much research, I determined that the best way to do this was to run both the front and back end on a single server.
I used the frontend-maven-plugin to build the React components into a location where Springboot can serve from.  And I used the heroku-maven-plugin to deploy to heroku

Here's the relatvant part of my pom:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>${frontend-src-dir}</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>${frontend-src-dir}</installDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>$heroku-app-name</appName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```